# XSD: restrict simpleContent within a complexType for empty element

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

Here is the definition of empty element:

```
<xs:complexType name="processingHook">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:anyType">
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:element name="callMyApp" type="processingHook" />
```

And XML-document:

```
<callMyApp
     xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
     xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation='note.xsd'></callMyApp>
```

Validation is successful, but when I replace `xs:complexContent` with `xs:simpleContent`, I get an error:

> src-ct.2.2: Complex Type Definition Representation Error for type
>   'processingHook'.  When a complexType with simpleContent restricts a
>   complexType with mixed content and emptiable particle, then there must
>   be a `<simpleType>` among the children of restriction

I'm new to XSD, so I don't understand the cause of the error.

[Here](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/xml/schema/ch07_03.htm) I've found elements definitions, which allow restrict `simpleContent` within a `complexType` (but not for empty element):

```
<xs:element name="title">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:restriction base="tokenWithLangAndNote">
                <xs:maxLength value="255"/>
                <xs:attribute name="lang" type="xs:language"/>
                <xs:attribute name="note" use="prohibited"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

So, why it doesn't work with empty elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I try this schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:complexType name="processingHook">
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:anyType">
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:element name="callMyApp" type="processingHook" />
</xs:schema>
```

I get this error message from oXygen (which presumably comes directly from Xerces):

*Complex Type Definition Representation Error for type 'processingHook'.  When a complexType with simpleContent restricts a complexType with mixed content and emptiable particle, then there must be a `<simpleType>` among the children of `<restriction>`.*

and this (much simpler) error message from Saxon 9.9:

*The base type of the simple type at test.xsd#6 is not a simple type*

The Saxon error message here is possibly over-simplified; but let's see what the rules say:

In §343 of XML Schema 1.0 Part 1 we have:

**Schema Representation Constraint: Complex Type Definition Representation OK**

```
    ...all of the following must be true:

    2 If the <simpleContent> alternative is chosen, all of the following must be true:
    2.1 The type definition ·resolved· to by the ·actual value· of the base
 [attribute] must be one of the following:
    2.1.1 ...
    2.1.2 only if the <restriction> alternative is also chosen, a 
complex type definition whose {content type} is mixed and a particle 
which is ·emptiable·, as defined in Particle Emptiable (§3.9.6);
    2.1.3 ...
    2.2 If clause 2.1.2 above is satisfied, then there must be a 
<simpleType> among the [children] of <restriction>.
```

So the Xerces error message (as is often the case) is lifted fairly direcly from the spec, and references the clause number (§2.2) containing the relevant rule.

§2.1.2 is saying that a complex type that is emptiable and has variety="mixed" allows something like `<p>12.3</p>`, and therefore a complex type with simple content (CTSC) of `xs:decimal` should be considered a valid restriction, because every instance of the CTSC is also a valid instance of the complex type that it is restricting. But §2.2 is essentially saying that when you define a CTSC, you must define what the type of the simple content is. Even if you want to allow the simple content to be any string, you have to say so.

I suspect one of the reasons for this is that an `xs:restriction` will normally define one or more constraining facets (such as `minInclusive` or `pattern`), and the meaning of a constraining facet depends on the simple type that you are restricting.

Comment: So, have I understood you correctly: when `restriction` is used, complex types with simple content *require* data content definition (ie, some simple type), whereas complex types with complex content *don't require* a definition of the content model (as shown in my 1st code snippet in the post)?

Comment: The way you define a restriction is completely different for simple types and complex types. For simple types you define facets that define further constraints beyond those in the base type; for complex types you define the new content model, which must be a valid restriction (subset) of the old one. An empty content model is a valid restriction of any content model that permits empty content.

Comment: To put it another way, a restriction of a complex type DOES require a definition of the content model, but if you say nothing then that's a valid definition of the empty content model.